# How to print a string in fasm?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm learning how to write boot sector assembler programs in FASM, and I'm having trouble printing a string. The tutorial has given me an assignment in which I'm supposed to write my own print_string routine as seen here:

```
include 'routines.ASM'

mov bx, hello_msg
call print_string
mov bx, goodbye_msg
call print_string
jmp $ ; now hang!

hello_msg:
db 'Hey there world!', 0 ;;0 tells routine to stop printing

goodbye_msg:
db 'time to do some stuff!', 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

My routines.asm file is as follows:

```
print_char:
mov ah, 0xe
int 0x10
ret

print_string:
;; compare the char at address to zero. return if 0. Otherwise print, increment, repeat

mov ax, [bx]
cmp al, 0
je exit
call print_char
add bx, 1
jmp print_string

exit:
ret
```

What I'm trying to do is use the address stored in BX to get the location of the character I need to print, increment, and continue until terminated by 0. However, bochs is giving me the error

```
using of nonexisting segment register 7
```

and it's not printing anything onscreen.

What am I doing wrong - have I overlooked something? Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Since your code is included first, you somehow have to make sure the control gets to the proper entry point. You could move the `include 'routines.ASM'` to just before `hello_msg`.  PS: you want `mov al, [bx]` instead of `mov ax, [bx]`, but that's harmless in this case.

Comment: WOW! I did *NOT* know how important the location of including anything is! I moved it as you said, and it prints garbled characters to the screen. But at least it's printing something, so I'm on the right track!

Comment: You also need to set up `ds` properly, e.g. `mov ax, 7c0h; mov ds, ax` (if you assume an offset of 0).

Comment: Speaking of offsets, I didn't include the line "org 0x7c00" because (for some odd reason) it compiled to above 512 bytes, to which bochs complained. But I included it again, lo and behold it does exactly as it's supposed to now!

Comment: With `org 7c00` you should do `xor ax, ax; mov ds, ax` to make sure it's set up properly. Otherwise it might break under other environments. The reason it came out more than 512 is presumably because you put the org after the include so it already emitted code at offset 0 too.